# array single value validation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

I have an array, values are assigned there: true or false. I'm using vuelidate.

```
selectedDays: [
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false
    ],
```

This is my template, when one of the checkboxes is checked, value is changing to true. It is necessary to write a validation that checks for the presence of at least one true value, if none of the checkboxes is checked, the validation worked.

```
<p class="invalid-feedback mt-3" v-if="v$.selectedDays.$dirty && v$.selectedDays.$error">Пожалуйста, выберите дни тренировок</p>
<template v-for="(item, index) in daysList" :key="item.id">
<v-checkbox
 hide-details
 color="indigo"
 v-model="selectedDays[index]"
 :label="item.title"
 >
 </v-checkbox>
                                
 </template>
```

This is my validation:

```
        selectedDays: {
            $each: helpers.forEach({
                sameAs: sameAs(true)
            })
        }
```

But it doesn't work. I tried to write custom validation:

```
let check = this.selectedDays.some(function() {
if (this.selectedDays === true) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}});
```

And I don't understand how to embed this in vuelidate. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

The custom validation is wrong, it needs to validate if some element in array is true:

```js
let check = this.selectedDays.some(function(element) {
if (element === true) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}});
```

or:

```js
let check = this.selectedDays.some(e => e === true);
```

Comment: so, how can i use it in validations()?

Comment: You can write inside `validations()`, create a method an pass inside `selectedDays` prop @AlmatKaipzhanov